# asp.net mvc clearing a form after post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewstate

I'm a .net programmer, but new to mvc.

I created a new mvc page with a simple form on it - 2 textboxes and a submit button.
Upon posting, it goes to my server side method, where the user info is entered into the db, and then I want to return the user to the same exact form but empty again.

When I use "return View("Index", new myIndexObject());" it returns the user to the same page with the form, but with the information he already filled out as if there was ViewState on the controls.
How do i get rid of this ??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Comment: Thanks!!
Surprisingly, It wasn't easy finding this solution on the net... :)

Answer (score 1):

This solves the Problem but in Case the User or page needs to be Notified by the Message 
Tempdata can be used.

```
TempData["Message"] = "Your Message";
 return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

and In View Check like this

```
<%if (TempData["Message"] != null)
  { %>

  <div class="message"> <h2><%= TempData["Message"] as string %> </h2></div>
    <% } %>
```